# In Draw control and draw modes starts drawing on map onmouseenter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl, mapbox-gl-draw

**mapbox-gl-js version**: @latest
**mapbox-gl-draw version**: @latest

#### Expected Behavior

I add the draw control on map init and I have custom button for multiple draw types.
 Rectangle, Free Polygon. so in DEV environment drawing works completely fine and perfect.
In dev recorded video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m1TEqQMjOgdDvFxk2HRihJMmuqLZX5WS/view

#### Actual Behavior after build

When I create build in react it does not behave correct.
after building project DrawControl starts drawing on mouseover automatically but it should start drawing on Click and end drawing on click. 
In build it starts on mouseenter and automatically stops while the cursor is on the map.
If you need any.
This is current behavior after build.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aH0G7bcU9_fP3g6-o1l0n782fZzyu5w_/view

Please tell me if you need anything else to help me.
Thanks.